# How to filter on view using complex query

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to filter on a view which emits bookName and bookItem.

emit([doc.basicInfo.bookName,doc.basicInfo.bookItem], 1);

it gives me below result without any query:

```
{"total_rows”:10,”offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"d4e5548fb01e6e2c559e702fe7b138ad","key":["correctaccouts","billing"],"value":1},
{"id":"863c46c645b6344719a08231606f2a7d","key":["credeaccount","system"],"value":1},
{"id":"68d39e64c406127960dc735e8167eee3","key":["credeaccount11","system"],"value":1},
{"id":"1ab4d31588d76a42e85b526a316074de","key":["mayankamazon","billing"],"value":1},
{"id":"3204f5db5df91886373f95995ce09a2d","key":["mayankazure","asset"],"value":1},
{"id":"452c040048fb2b779205b3785615d368","key":["mayankmaaa","system"],"value":1},
{"id":"23f01f7bc60c2c8f24f6b741584a69fa","key":["TEST_AWS_Delete212sss12","asset"],"value":1},
{"id":"f0093f474e0d50f046b9fdc9145bdc91","key":["vijeth-myteam111115555555","asset"],"value":1},
{"id":"c3bce8dd1482d841f445fbd617ba1db7","key":["vijeth-myteam11111555sss5555","asset"],"value":1},
{"id":"347479ba91696b73f4a57252cd00a358","key":["vijeth-myteamOnly","asset"],"value":1}
]}
```

Now I am trying to query on it using complex keys:

satrtkey=[{},"asset"]&endkey=[{},"asset"]

It should return me:

```
{"total_rows”:5,”offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"3204f5db5df91886373f95995ce09a2d","key":["mayankazure","asset"],"value":1},
{"id":"23f01f7bc60c2c8f24f6b741584a69fa","key":["TEST_AWS_Delete212sss12","asset"],"value":1},
{"id":"f0093f474e0d50f046b9fdc9145bdc91","key":["vijeth-myteam111115555555","asset"],"value":1},
{"id":"c3bce8dd1482d841f445fbd617ba1db7","key":["vijeth-myteam11111555sss5555","asset"],"value":1},
{"id":"347479ba91696b73f4a57252cd00a358","key":["vijeth-myteamOnly","asset"],"value":1}
]}
```

But it still gives me all 10 records. I want to filter only records of type "asset".

Answer (score 0):

To use key ranges, you must narrow down your research starting with the left fields to the right fields.

For example, if  your key would be: `[doc.basicInfo.bookItem,doc.basicInfo.bookName]`

You could search with `start_key=["asset",null]&end_key=["asset",{}]`

**Also**, your current query is equivalent to `key=[{},"asset"]`. Instead, you should have tried: `start_key=[null,"asset"]&end_key=[{},"asset"]` but it should not work.

## Example

View:

```
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.basicInfo.bookItem,doc.basicInfo.bookName], 1);
}
```

Query:

```
http://localhost:5984/<db>/_design/<design_name>/_view/<view_name>?include_docs=true&inclusive_end=true&start_key=%5B%22asset%22%2Cnull%5D&end_key=%5B%22asset%22%2C%7B%7D%5D
```

Comment: @Cote I tried the solution shared by you, but none of them seems to work, I got empty result instead.

Comment: Can you share an example set of data and the view you used? From my end, this is working: `start_key=["asset",null]&end_key=["asset",{}]` if you use the correct view keys.